# Can decompress RAR files with 7z.exe command line?

Tags: 7-zip, extract, rar

Can extract RAR files from the terminal with 7z.exe? Thanks!

This lines doesn´t works on a Extract.bat file.

```
7z.exe X Xbox.rar -o
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested with 7-zip v9.20 on Windows 7 and it worked fine on a .rar file. The command I ran was:

`"\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x TestFiles.rar`

Running the executable without arguments gives the full usage, which shows the `-o` argument requires an output directory given as a parameter.